# Copy all data in all sheet incld blank in one sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba scrip that will copy the data in all sheets and paste it in another one toi group al the data:

```
Sub Recap()
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "Feuil1" Then
        sh.[A7].Resize(sh.[A65536].End(xlUp).Row - 1, 13).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Feuil1").[A65536].End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next sh
```

My problem is that the script does not take ALL the data, it somehow stop at some point, I assume that it is becose I have some merged cells or blank rows. 
Anybody has an idea of what I should change?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `somehow stop at some point` ...  at what point? At what sheet? We need more information to help you.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks for your quick answer :). The sript did well, it took data from all the sheets but not all the data. It didn't copy the data from the last 22 rows in the last sheet.

Comment: what is different about the last 22 rows of data in the last sheet?

Comment: All the rows are differents, I mean that in all af them there are blank cells or merged cells. The thing that I do not quite get is that the rows 42, 59 (last row copie) and 70 are exactly the same. I tried to clear formating and unmerge all cells before the script but it does not Change anything. The only thing that changes is when I add a row with "-" in each cell after last row.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I found the solution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after little research, I found another way to calculate the *RowSize* in the *Resize* function:

Istead of :

```
sh.[A7].Resize(sh.[A65536].End(xlUp).Row - 1, 13).Copy
```

I calculated the *Row* using *UsedRange* function:

```
sh.[A7].Resize(sh.UsedRange.Rows(sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row - 1, 13).Copy
```

The final VBA works perfectly well:

```
Sub Recap()
Dim sh As Worksheet
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "Feuil1" Then
        sh.[A7].Resize(sh.UsedRange.Rows(sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row - 1, 13).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Feuil1").[A65536].End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next sh
```